# How do I change which interface gateway pfsense resolves to?

Tags: networking, dns, pfsense

I've recently extended my network from one flat LAN to a couple interfaces using additional physical ports on my router and VLANs. I've kept the old interface up while I'm migrating and for testing and renamed it Legacy.

The legacy interface uses a `192.168.85.0/24` network. My new network for infrastructure like the router, APs and switch uses `192.168.10.0/24` and is the default interface for untagged traffic on that port. When I ping my router using it's FQDN from any network it resolves to the gateway address of the Legacy interface. That is, from a host on the `192.168.10.0/24` range if I ping pfsense.home.arpa it resolves to `192.168.85.1` instead of `192.168.10.1`. I don't see anything special in the interface settings for my legacy LAN that would tell pfsense it's the "default" so I'm not sure how to change this.

Searching for solutions has been very difficult since all the keywords I can think of like "default gateway" "hostname resolution" etc. are much more related to more common concepts of interface default gateways and resolving the name of hosts within a network.

Just to clarify, I'm fine with all my new networks resolving to one IP when pinging the router, I don't need each one to resolve to its own default gateway, I just want to change what that one IP is from the gateway associated with my legacy interface to the one associated with my new infrastructure LAN.

Comment: You could make the question easier on the eye by breaking it down and add some whitespace.

Comment: Have you looked through the settings of pfSense's "DNS Resolver" or "DNS Something-else-I-forget" specifically? The plugin that controls Unbound or Dnsmasq makes mostly independent choices about what to add for the pfSense own entry... (It could be there is no setting, pfSense has strong feelings about the "LAN" interface being main vs "OPTx".)

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure it's just pfsense strongly defaulting to the first LAN interface that's created. It's not a huge deal, I was just curious if there was a fix or way to reassign the primary LAN. Doesn't seem to be the case.